# upload file via Ajax appending data with append() not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, forms

When I upload file to external server via Ajax call passing form data to `FormData();` via hidden input fields of the submitted form, everything works fine.

However, when I'm passing form data to `FormData();` by appending it to `FormData();`, it does not work.

How come that the processing of the data is somehow different when you pass data via hidden fields from when you append data. Since in the second case it doesn't work.

This method works:

```
$('#myform').on('submit', function(e){
    var formdata = new FormData(this);
    $.ajax({
        url: 'https://external-website.com/',
        type: 'POST',
        data: formdata,
        processData: false,
        contentType: false
    });
});

<form id="myform" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <input type="hidden" name="key1" value="value1">
    <input type="hidden" name="key2" value="value2">
    <input type="file" name="file">
    <input type="submit" value="Upload">
</form>
```

This method does not work:

```
$('#myform').on('submit', function(e){
    var formdata = new FormData(this);
    formdata.append('key1', 'value1');
    formdata.append('key2', 'value2');
    $.ajax({
        url: 'https://external-website.com/',
        type: 'POST',
        data: formdata,
        processData: false,
        contentType: false
    });
});


<form id="myform" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <input type="file" name="file">
    <input type="submit" value="Upload">
</form>
```

Comment: You marked my answer as best, but it does not answers anything if you are using the `e.preventDefault()`. Did you manage to find out the real cause of the problem?

Comment: Do you know what is the platform/technology/stack this server is using? Is it some kind of the public service, which I could also access and try? I'm just curious why the hell it does not work.

Comment: Thanks. I'm not a PHP guy, but from what I google and could understand this function allows you to generate a form with certain parameters, which on submit will uppload a file to Amazon s3 and store it somewhere there. Since you don't want to have hidden fields you must be generating some js code to add these parameters to your FormData and probably this is were you might have an error. Typo, or encoding problem, or something else. I suggest you compare the requests generated by form and by js code very thoroughly. The error must be there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't see you calling `e.preventDefault();` in form submit handler which means your form is also submitted the usual way (in addition to an ajax request you send). This might be the case why it works in a first example - you have all the fields in a form and it's submitted.
Check out the network tab in dev tools to see how may requests are done and if your page is reloaded. Also trace on server how many requests are received and with what parameters.

Comment: I do use `e.preventDefault();` I just did not include it in the example. Both methods send the same parameters. Thank you for your advises, but this problem is still a mystery to me.

Comment: Ok, I tested your code in latest Chrome and the requests, sent by both examples, are basically identical, except that in the second example the first part of the payload is the file and then key1 and key2. What server are you submitting to? Try checking the request payload there.

Comment: Thank you. The order of file and keys was causing this problem. Keys must come before file. Your comment gave me idea that resolved this problem, so I marked your answer accepted.

Answer (score 0):

```
let formdata = new FormData;
formdata.append('file', $(YourElement).files[0]);
```

I think files is an array that can be accessed when [0] is placed in front of it.